# Tensorflow Recommenders : Getting back a array of tensors instead of actual value

Tags: python, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I am trying to use the TFRS libraries for my custom datasets and leverage context features in the candidate tower, following the notebook in the below link :  https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/context_features

However this notebook does not have code snippet to get the actual predictions.

I tried to use the following code to get the predictions :

```
# Create a model that takes in raw query features, and
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.query_model)
# recommends movies out of the entire movies dataset.

index.index_from_dataset(candidates=movies.batch(128).map(model.candidate_model))
# Get recommendations.
_, titles= index({"user_id": tf.constant(["42"])})
#_, titles= index(tf.constant(["42"]))
#print(f"Recommendations for user 42: {index[0, :20]}")
index({"user_id": tf.constant(["42"])})
```

But it gives me tensors and not actual values, as below :

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[1.9809544, 1.9188036, 1.9123437, 1.892283 , 1.8718885, 1.8687773,
         1.8661623, 1.8649822, 1.8454401, 1.8244784]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[ 979,  913,  788,  563, 1311,  112, 1420,  656,  610, 1155]],
       dtype=int32)>)
```

Can anyone please help with pointer on either directly getting the predictions or a quick way to reverse look up these tensors back to meaningful values ?

Comment: 979, 913, ... are the labels of the titles recommended for user 42?

Answer (score 2):

In your output

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[1.9809544, 1.9188036, 1.9123437, 1.892283 , 1.8718885, 1.8687773,
         1.8661623, 1.8649822, 1.8454401, 1.8244784]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[ 979,  913,  788,  563, 1311,  112, 1420,  656,  610, 1155]],
       dtype=int32)>)
```

These are the scores of your recommendations:

```
[1.9809544, 1.9188036, 1.9123437, 1.892283 , 1.8718885, 1.8687773,
             1.8661623, 1.8649822, 1.8454401, 1.8244784]
```

and these are the actual recommendations:

```
[ 979,  913,  788,  563, 1311,  112, 1420,  656,  610, 1155]
```

It seems that for your custom datasets you either have input the wrong data to get these recommendations or the data is correct but you have converted the meaningful values to numbers before input.

To get the actual recommendations the following will give you a python list of recommendations:

```
_, titles= index({"user_id": tf.constant(["42"])})    
titles[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! After going through half the internet, I found it here that how to index into BruteForce model with multiple key dataset `index({"user_id": tf.constant(["42"])})`. I did not find this in tensorflow recommender documentation. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Not really explicitly documented.